# Extract the end of a value and place this in a new column based on certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to extract the end of a value and use this as a determining factor for a new column

Data

```
id  type
a   h_db-nd
a   h_db-nd
a   h_bu
```

Desired

```
id  type       status
a   h_db-nd    nd
a   h_db-nd    nd
a   h_bu       d
```

If the ending is nd place nd beside it in the new column, if not, the default is 'd'

Doing

```
df['status'] = df['type'].str.extract()
```

I am performing an extract, but still troubleshooting this.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Why the `d` in the last row? There's no `d` in `type`.

Comment: This is default , if there is no -nd at the end, the default value is 'd'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the condition [`pandas.Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) alongside [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
df['status'] = np.where(df['type'].str.endswith("-nd"), "nd", "d")
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
import pandas as pd, re

dct = {"id": ["a", "a", "a"],
       "type": ["h_db-nd", "h_db-nd", "h_bu"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

df['status'] = df['type'].str.extract('-([^-]+)$').fillna('d')

print(df)
```

Which yields

```
  id     type status
0  a  h_db-nd     nd
1  a  h_db-nd     nd
2  a     h_bu      d
```

This is probably more suited if you have more than just `d/-nd`.
Otherwise go with [**@Michael's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67826698/1231450).

Comment: maybe another option with your regex pattern `df['type']=df['type'].str.extract('-([^-]+)$').fillna('d')` without importing re module

Comment: @AnuragDabas: Thanks for the suggestion. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but gets the work done.

```py
df['status'] = df['type'].str[-2:].map({"nd":"nd"}).fillna("d")
```

Comment: You can also use the apply method ```df['status'] = df['type'].apply(lambda x: "nd" if x.endswith("nd') else "d")```